# iOS Firebase Database Security. Create New App User: Checking for Existence of Username

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, heroku, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS app where all user and data functionality is handled through firebase. For all required firebase functions, we have set the rights on firebase set such that they are secure (i.e., everyone can only read/write the parts of the database that are relevant to them).

Now, in the “create new user” screen of my app, obviously no user is signed in yet, but I would like to check for availability of the desired email address and username.

How can I conduct the check without making a list of all email addresses and usernames openly accessible in the database (i.e., setting the rights such that everyone can read them).

Keeping an openly accessible list of usernames in the database in my view is a security risk. On the other hand of course no user is signed in when on the “create user” screen, so I don’t know how to restrict the access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways around this. Here are a couple suggestions:

Sign the user in anonymously before choosing a username. This would then give them the access you're looking for without making the data public. Then, when the user creates an account, the anonymous account can be converted, as shown in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth).

Use an [HTTP-triggered Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), passing the username the user wants to try as a query. Inside the function, check the database for the existence of the username, and then respond to the HTTP call accordingly.

I'd probably do the former because it'll return a quicker response. Cloud Functions can take time to spin up if they haven't run for a while.

Comment: Agreed: this sounds like a great use-case for Cloud Functions, so that the code that can read all usernames is running on Google's servers.

Comment: Super. Thank you both.